# Using Logic with External Minilogue XD: Logic changes the instrument for midi tracks

Tags: logic-pro, korg

I am loading some midi files of popular music I found into logic and setting Logic to control my Minilogue XD with the midi notes.  However, when the midi section starts, the Minilogue XD changes its instrument.  I can't find where this might be getting set.

[image]

Comment: Program change - find it in the list editor - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/logicpro/lgcp21591cf3/mac

Comment: Most multi channel midi files have pre programmed patch assignments, usually based on the 127 general midi standard patches. If your Minilogue has a GM patch bank and you select that bank first you should get the right sounds. If not you will have to reassign the patch changes at the beginning of the event list to the correct ones for your synth OR delete them and create your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tetsujin pointed out, this is caused by the Program Change event and can be modified (deleted!) in the List Editor. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/logicpro/lgcp21591cf3/mac